# When creating QWebSocket object, it shows QSslSocket warning messages

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, openssl

It consists of two processes communicating via WebSocket.  It worked without any problem but today I executed the process I got these messages.

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CONF_CTX_new

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CONF_CTX_free

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CONF_CTX_set_ssl_ctx

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CONF_CTX_set_flags

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CONF_CTX_finish

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CONF_cmd

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected
```

these messages are shown when creating QWebSocket object.

```
myWebSocket = new QWebSocket(QString(), QWebSocketProtocol::VersionLatest, parent);
```

I have no idea why this happens. only my PC shows this message. if
I run the application on different PC, nothing happens.

Windows 10, Qt 5.11.1

Comment: Have you tried to use ignoreSslErrors() method?

Comment: @AndreySemenov - Yes I did. but the messages are shown even before calling the method.  the biggest problem is after the messages, the websocket doesn't work properly.

Comment: It looks like those messages are shown by this code in qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp

#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x10002000L
    RESOLVEFUNC(SSL_CONF_CTX_new);
    RESOLVEFUNC(SSL_CONF_CTX_free);
    RESOLVEFUNC(SSL_CONF_CTX_set_ssl_ctx);
    RESOLVEFUNC(SSL_CONF_CTX_set_flags);
    RESOLVEFUNC(SSL_CONF_CTX_finish);
    RESOLVEFUNC(SSL_CONF_cmd);
#endif

Comment: do you have open ssl library installed on your system?

Comment: No. but It worked well till yesterday. and the application runs even a newly installed pc, I don't think there is open ssl library in it.